# Contradiction in proof of boundedness of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, upper-lower-bounds

We want to prove that function $f$, which is continuous on $[a,b]$, is bounded from above. There is one step in the proof that I don't understand.

> If $f$ is not bounded from above, then for every positive integer $n$
>   we can find a number $x_n$ in the interval such that $f(x_n) \gt n$.
>   The sequence of such $x_n$ has a point of accumulation $C$ in the
>   interval by the Weierstrass-Bolzano theorem. By continuity, given $1$,
>   there exists $\delta$ such that if $x \in [a,b]$ and $|x - C| \lt
> \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(C)| \lt 1$. In particular, $|f(x_n)| - |f(C)|
> \le |f(x_n) - f(C)| \le 1$, whence $n \lt f(x_n) \le 1 + |f(C)|$. **This is a contradiction for $n$ sufficiently large**, thus proving that $f$ is bound from above.

I don't see any contradiction. What's the problem with $f(x_n)$ being not larger than $1 + |f(C)|$ for every $n$?

Comment: to quote you need only to add `>` at the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get a contradiction when $n>1+|f(C)|$.

Comment: Of course! Now that was easy...